# What is the time complexity for a break statement?

Tags: c++, algorithm

both array are same
First array has one element extra added in between.

```
class Solution{
  public:
    int findExtra(int a[], int b[], int n) {
        // add code here.
        int index=0,flag=0;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(a[i]-b[i]!=0){
                index=i;
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0) return n;
        else return index;
    }
};
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: The `break` statement doesn't affect the time complexity of the `findExtra` function. On average the loop will execute `n/2` times before it stops. So from a time complexity point of view, it's no different than if the loop went all the way to the end every time. O(n/2) is still O(n).

Comment: That is a very wordy linear search. The worst case is if the item you are looking for is the last item in the array. That's O(n). (The best case is if it is the first item, which is Ω(1).)

Comment: @Dúthomhas That means it is *O(N)*.

Comment: A statement, including `break`, doesn't have a time complexity of its own. It depends how often it is executed compared to *N*. In this case your code is poor as you should `return i` instead of the `break`, and `return n` if you fall through it.